# Ground wires on a light fixture

Tags: electrical

I am trying to replace a chandelier - there is a black, white and bare copper wire (right now has yellow cap in picture)coming out of the ceiling, the silver fixture frame has a green screw and the fixture has a black white and copper wire. Do the two copper wires connect? Do i need to use the green screw to ground them?

I connected both copper wires but the light didnt work. And guidance is appreciated
[image: light fixture]
[image: ceiling]

Comment: Pictures added - black, white and bare

Comment: you have to connect the black and white also ... follow the installation instructions

Comment: The question is about the 2 copper wires, do i connect them or and do they both need to attach to the green screw

Comment: The copper wires are just there for your safety mainly.  They are not part of the circuit that deals with the light working, so if they are connected or not should not matter for the light to work.  Best practice is to loop one around the green screw with enough hanging out to use a wire nut to connect to the other one.  The light not working is a different question/problem that the copper wires have nothing to do with.

Comment: put the ground wire (bare copper) on the other side of the bar in the second picture ... loop around the green screw ... leave the end as long as possible ... use the yellow wire nut to connect the braided ground wire

Comment: Since you have a long bare copper whip on the chandelier, I like to loop that around the green screw, leaving a tail long enough to nut to the bare wire coming out of the ceiling.  I do this because the loop gives me something to hang the fixture from while I nut the black and white wires, freeing up a hand.  Obviously, if the fixture is really heavy that's not a good idea, but if it's fairly light it's fine.